# A moderation dashboard for chat

Tags: feature-request, chat, moderator-tools, moderation

Chat Moderation has recently been a topic in the [MSE Town Hall Chat #2](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/280309/join-us-for-the-second-mse-town-hall-on-wednesday-june-22nd). This is not only due to the fact that chat moderation is [percieved as inconsistent](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/238176/can-we-get-some-official-guidelines-for-chat-suspension-lengths) by chat users, [chat flags being broken](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/239343/222299) and room owner-tools (or the RO system in general) having [some issues related to moderation capabilities.](https://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/transcript/89?m=5027478#5027478)

There has been a [Guide to Moderating Chat](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/271267/a-guide-to-moderating-chat) that outlines clear rules. The Room Owner tools and chat flags have been talked about at length in the Town Hall chat (and other posts).

One thing that I still find lacking about chat moderation is **retraceability**.

For some moderation actions there is a paper trail:

- Moving messages
- Changing Room Title / Topic / Tags
- Changing Room Owners
- Changing Feeds posted into rooms
- ...

For some others, there isn't:

- Kicking users

- Stars cancelled, Pins / Unpins
- ...

Unfortunately assembling the paper trail into a nice overview is incredibly hard. e.G.: just to aggregate how many messages were moved from a room you could try to [search for "messages moved to"](https://chat.stackexchange.com/search?room=8595&q=messages%20moved%20to) which is the best guess at a paper trail. Unfortunately that doesn't yield *any* relevant results:

[image: messages moved from and not to]

It's even worse for actions that don't even have paper trails. To facilitate discussions about chat moderations and to have *proper* accountability it's important to know what moderation actions were taken (and when).

**I propose that there should be a dashboard for moderation actions.**
From a moderator I heard that mods would love something like this.

The dashboard should be available to Moderators and Room Owners. Room Owners should only be allowed to see actions taken in rooms they are **currently** owning. Furthermore Room Owners should only see actions that they *could take themselves*. Moderators should be able to see all moderation actions.

In the best case, that dashboard would be filterable by:

- Room
- Action taken
- User Taking the action
- Date

I imagine this would also help CMs investigating incidents involving chat

Comment: There is a trail for kicks, actually, but it's mod only.